# SAS Proc TTest - Difference from fixed value

Tags: sas, proc

How do I test if a variable is significantly different from the value 15?

What value does the test need to be greater than for a confidence level of 95% that is it different (i.e 5% opportunity the average is 15?)

Answer (score 0):

To specify a null value to test against look at the H0 option. For the 5%, I assume is the alpha level. If your test is two sided then the default side option is fine, otherwise set that value to 1.

```
 Proc ttest data=sashelp.class h0=15 alpha=0.05 sides=2;
 Var age;
 Run;
```

All of these options are detailed in the documentation. The value used for comparison against the test statistic varies based on the sample size.

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_ttest_sect002.htm

UCLA offers a detailed walk through of Proc Ttest
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/output/ttest.htm